# How to convert classic cronjobs to cron expressions for quartz-scheduler

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am used to [cronjobs](https://crontab.guru/#0_1_*_*_*) like this:

> 0 1 * * *

In the java library quartz-scheduler they use cron expressions.

> 0 0 1 1/1 * ? *

Is there a way directly from quartz-scheduler or a other possability to convert or use the [old cronjobs](https://crontab.guru/#0_1_*_*_*) in quartz-scheduler?

Edit: I found something for JS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron-to-quartz is there a way in Java?

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344453/how-to-convert-cron-string-to-scheduleexpression-in-java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found some library in Java that might help you: https://github.com/jmrozanec/cron-utils. Although, I haven't used it personally.

The JS code from the library that you've found doesn't seem very complex, so the alternative would be to replicate that one in Java.

BTW, what's your need for such a conversion, can you give us more context? Is it something automatic that needs to be performed, or is it a one-time conversion only?